# .replace replacing wrong values

Tags: c#

I am working on a method that creates a string builder called SQL and using SQL.Replace to replace parts of that with values.

During debug the values are what they should be. Until i get to the .WriteToDatabase(SQL.ToString()); part then the values seem to be replaced with the number i have assigned to them.

So for example I have string shift this = morning shift until i get to .WriteToDatabase.
I have tried replacing the positining in string builder and in Sql with no joy.
Code

```
 public static void InsertPumaLadleControlProcessMonitoring(string ladleNo, string shift1, string LadleTemp, string Source, string Destination1, string Destination2, string Destination3, string Destination4, string pourTime, string RodsTibor, string Rodsr, string chunksMg, string DegasCycleTime, string Denisty, string OOT)
    {
        try
        {
            string operatorID = clsPublic.loggedInUserId;
            StringBuilder SQL = new StringBuilder(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("InsertPumaLadleControlProcessMonitoring"));
            SQL = SQL.Replace("param1", ladleNo);
            SQL = SQL.Replace("param2", LadleTemp);
            SQL = SQL.Replace("param3", Source);
            SQL = SQL.Replace("param4", Destination1); 
            SQL = SQL.Replace("param5", Destination2);
            SQL = SQL.Replace("param6", Destination3);
            SQL = SQL.Replace("param7", Destination4);
            SQL = SQL.Replace("param8", pourTime);
            SQL = SQL.Replace("param9", Rods);
            SQL = SQL.Replace("param10", Rodsr);
            SQL = SQL.Replace("param11", chunksMg);
            SQL = SQL.Replace("param12", DegasCycleTime);
            SQL = SQL.Replace("param13", Denisty);
            SQL = SQL.Replace("param14", OOT);
            SQL = SQL.Replace("param15", shift1);

            clsPublic.sqlDB.WriteToDatabase(SQL.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //clsPublic.appLog.Error("Cannot add Record");
            //throw new Exception("Cannot add record");
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot Add Record" + e);
        }
    }
```

So Shift 1 is = Moring Shift but it seems to be changing to 15 when it gets to .WriteToDatabase(SQL.ToString());
Anyone Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: if you have `param10`, `param11`, `param12`, then replacing `param1` with something sounds extraordinarily dangerous; `param10` becomes `Foo0` - is it as simple as that? but.... why oh why oh why are you replacing parameters with values? that is really really the wrong idea of parameterisation

Comment: This is code that i have been given to edit.

Comment: not sure how that changes anything...

Comment: Please allow me to state very clearly: if this is the usual approach to data access used in the application, then ***stop now***; your (and everyone's) direct and immediate priority needs to be: to fix that insanity. The code as presented is *just insane*. That is *not* what parameterization means, and the existing data access code is **ridiculously** broken, by every measure of such. It needs attention; now.

Comment: I would have to change the whole project which at this present time is not viable. Im not sure as to why they have taken this approach with their Data.

Comment: "Im not sure as to why they have taken this approach with their Data." - then: ask.

Comment: "So Shift 1 is = Moring Shift but it seems to be changing to 15 when it gets to .WriteToDatabase(SQL.ToString()); Anyone Any ideas? Thanks" - is `ladleNo` perhaps `1` ? that would result in `param15` becoming simply `15`

Comment: Got it thanks for your answers i got this piece working. Il make sure to change how the code we have at present and the code we write is structured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SQL.Replace("param1", ladleNo);` will replace all occurences of `"param1"`, even those in `"param10"`, `"param11"` etc.

Having said that: You should really be using parameters instead.

Comment: Even if i use 25 instead of 15 i still get the same issues

Comment: @Inkey indeed, because the replace of "param2" will impact "param25"

Answer (score 4):

You should use parameters, and not replace their names with values in query.

Comment: Thanks this is not my code just code i have been given to make changes on

Comment: Adding support for parameters in queries would be a nice change to make :)